# Area of intersection between line and circle?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

I have a circle $\mathcal{C}$ and a line $\mathcal{L}$ in the euclidean plane. Let say that the equation of the circle and the line are given respectively by: $$E_{\mathcal{C}}: \left(x-x_0\right)^2+\left(y-y_0\right)^2=r^2.$$
$$E_{\mathcal{L}}: x=d.$$

I want to find the area of the intersection of the circle and the line. How to do this?

Is it something like this?

$$\left(d-x_0\right)^2+\int_{-1}^{1}\left(y-y_0\right)^2\textrm{d}y.$$

[image]

Comment: What is meant by area of intersection? The area of intersection between a disk and a line segment is $0$.

Comment: I want the intersection between the circle and the half plane ($x\leq d$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A parametrization of the upper half of the circle of radius $1$ around the origin is $$
  y(x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2} \text{.}
$$
Thus, the area of the part of the unit disc left of the line $x=c$ is (assuming $-1 \leq c \leq 1$, of course) $$
  A_c = 2\int_{-1}^c \sqrt{1 - x^2} \,dx \text{.}
$$

In the general case, i.e. for circles of arbitrary radius and center, you can adapt this method by finding a useable $y(x)$ (Hint: You get $y(x)$ from the pythagorean theorem). Or, just observe that you can just translate and scale the coordinate to move the circle's center to the origin and make it's radius $1$. Then use the translated and scaled $c$ to compute $A_c$, and finally scale the result back. Note that if you scale one axis by factor $\lambda$, all areas get scaled by $\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks but the thing is I have no idea of the limit of $x$ and $y$ (why you choose $-1$ and $1$?). Only thing I know is the center of the circle $(x_0, y_0)$ and it's radius $r$. Maybe I do not write the question good. I will ask another one in a moment.

Comment: @zighalo Your question is fine, you just need to figure *out* the limits. I showed you the solution for a *particular* disc (i.e. the unit disc). From that, you can figure out the general case. Don't ask another question, posting multiple similar or even identical questions is heavily frowned upon here!

Comment: Please see my new question. It is different now. If it is not I will delete it now. Just tell me I will wait for your reply.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744013/area-of-intersection-between-random-half-plan-and-circle

Comment: Check out terms like Sagitta, Apothem, and Chord on Mathworld: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sagitta.html

Comment: @zighalo Haven't I told you, in very unambiguous words, to *not* post another question about this?

Comment: I deleted it. I thought it is different. I thought also that there is no issue for you to tell me that is duplicate. Anyway, thank you for your help.